# how do I install the qt demos/examples in my Opensuse?

Tags: c++, qt

I have Qt creator installed in my OpenSuse. I would like to view all the qt demos and examples, however Qt Creator says "Examples Not Installed." Where do I find the examples and demos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing the `libqt4-devel-doc` package:

as root:

```
zypper in libqt4-devel-doc
```

Most of the files provided by this package are located in `/usr/lib/qt4/demos` (x86) and `/usr/lib64/qt4/demos` (x86_64). Once installed you can execute `qtdemo` from your favorite terminal emulator (or from ALT+F2 run dialog).

Probably you will also need/want the `libqt4-devel-doc-data` package.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have installed development package for qt(libqtX-dev). You can find Examples and Demos at `/usr/lib/qt4`

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for Qt version 5:

as root:

`zypper in libqt5-qtdoc`

will provide you will all examples